# Variable meaning / value in a comma separated syntax

Tags: javascript, angular

Could you tell me what this `i` means after the comma. I am struggling to understand this syntax or even find it in the internet.

```
let i;
this.questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question'), i;
```

`i` is not used anymore in the function

If setting a debugger after this lines. `i` is undefined

Comment: Looks like a useless implementation of the comma operator. Same as `(this.questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question')), undefined;`

Comment: You don't need it. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be of any use indeed.

As an information, it's just to declare / instantiate your variables. Take a look :

```js
let i, j;
j = 1, i = 2;
console.log(i, j);
```